# Am I using the php session the right way?

Tags: php, session

I am currently building a network and I am using php to do it. I have a code that is working but I am not sure it's the most right and secure way to do it.
For simplification I have 4 files : Index(index.php) / Member Area(profile.php) / Sign-in (signin.php) / Login page(homepage.php).
When the user sign in and submit user and password the infos are sent to signin.php and if they are correct a session is created using this code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Now in the index.php what I do is I check if a session is already created if yes the user see profile.php if not he sees homepage.php and for this purpuse I am using this code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
include('homepage.php');
die();
}
else{
include('profile.php');
die();
}
```

So if user is logged the index will show him his member area if not the index will show him the login form.
Can I rely on this to be secure ?
Im I doing it the right way ? Do you have any suggestions.
Thank you all.

Comment: *"So if user is logged the index will show him his member area if not the index will show him the login form. Can I rely on this to be secure ? Im I doing it the right way ?"* - We don't know what the login looks like and how the registration works.

Comment: For login and registration they are totally fine. The main issue for me know is when user successfuly sign-in I should create a session for him and it must be a secure one. What do you think of my current code ?

Comment: "Totally fine"; oh I see. Well carry on then; what's the question? You're asking if it's secure; I don't know that, you have the register/login codes. You're using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` with a prepared statement I presume? The code you posted is only as safe as the register/login.

Comment: Yes for login registration I am using password_hash() and password_verify(). My question is for the php session is it secure for users ? and if the login process I am using is the right one to do? and if there is any other great suggestions. Thank you so much for your time fred.

Comment: IMO it is the most simplistic version of building a membership area. Your security measure depend on the goal of your app. Is it internal? Who is going to use it? What size will it eventually get? From what you got now, i would add one more thing. To prevent any hijacking, you might want to store the session id to the user database table e.g. column "logged_session_id" and validate that against the session key you better name "user_session_id". Do this on each request...

Comment: @Yolo Actually it's kinda a social network I predict to have many users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you might want to think deeply about what you require from your future application. It comes down to making as smart decisions as possible before hand. I dont want to take the wind from your wings... but.....

For example, if you want you site to be responsive (especially in future), not only in styling but also usability wise, you should already consider frameworks such as [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). And connecting them to an API that you write in a mix with PHP generated pages.

The site would end up being a mix of server side generated output and API responses filling the frontend with life when clicking/entering stuff.

The next step would be to consider using a PHP framework. Eventhough writing your own social netowrk site would be cool, but do you really need to reinvent all those wheels? You might want to look into [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) or [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/) etc... They offer secure login mechanisms that you can configure however you need them.

If you want to go the hard way.... (while you would still become a great programmer if you use frameworks) for starters look at [PHPAuth](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth) to help you kick start your login and authentication flow or [PHP-JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) for token based authentication (from any device). [GUMP](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP) for form validation. [PDO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for making secure queries to your database.

If applicable, when you come to the question which web server i would use for social network projects, i would go for nginx for now. It is highly scalable, has nice performance and is has the potential to be more secure than an apache setup for example.

Comment: Well I am not basically a programmer. I learned basic coding bymyself. and Yes I am using jquery, What I am thinking of is to make the mvp and get the project up and running with basic stuff and if it works I then can hire a team of programmer to work on it. Based on your experience Is it a great thing to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really 2 different things:

 1. Are you using sessions the right way? Technically yes. As long as the session is started before any output is send (including headers), then sessions will work. What you put into them and how you use that is up to you. Sessions just keep state between request. Default PHP sessions have some technical limitations depending on what you want to do, but most stuff should be fine.

2. Is it secure? This is different and really has less to do with sessions and more to do with general security.This boils down to how you are storing, transmitting, and encoding you passwords. There are many tutorials on how to do this well. Also, how well you secure your session cookie. Again, many good articles on this. Lastly, use SSL. Most up to date browsers won't even display a web site without one if it has any sort of security form on it.

Comment: Passwords are hashed using password_hash then stored in db and when sign in i verify using password verify in the sessions I store basically 3 elements. Username, id, and user name.